# value doesn't match format of datetime python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to convert a series in datetime in python, however it is giving me this error

> ValueError: time data '5/8/2018' does not match format '%d, %m, %Y' (match)

The code I'm using is

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, format='%d, %m, %Y').dt.date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say exactly without your data, but try this

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date
```

You're format has date as 5/8/2018 instead of 5, 8, 2018. For reference, I used this code to test.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['created_at'])
df = df.append({'created_at':'5/8/2018'}, ignore_index = True)
date = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date
```